# Removing list elements using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion, reverse

This is my question for class:
• deepReverse(L) takes as input a list of elements where some of those elements may be lists
themselves. deepReverse returns the reversal of the list where, additionally, any element that is
a list is also deepReversed. Here are some examples:

```
deepReverse([1, 2, 3])
[3, 2, 1]
deepReverse([1, [2, 3], 4])
[4, [3, 2], 1]
deepReverse([1, [2, [3, 4], [5, [6, 7], 8]]])
[[[8, [7, 6], 5], [4, 3], 2], 1]
```

For this problem, you will need the ability to test whether or not an element in the list is a list itself. To this
end, you can use the following line of code to test whether or not x is a list:

```
if isinstance(x, list):
if True you will end up here
else:
 if False you will end up here
```

this is the code i have so far:

```
def deepReverse(L):
    if L == []:
        return []
    elif isinstance(L[0], list):
        if True:
            list2 = L[0]
            return deepReverse(list2[1:]) + [list2[0]]
        else:
            deepReverse(L[1:]) + deepReverse(L[0])
    else:
        return deepReverse(L[1:]) + [L[0]]
```

for some reason it keeps returning [4,3,2,1] when i use the last test case. I do not understand why when I run the debugger once it gets to [3,4] going through each first element it just erases the second element. We are also not allowed to use any built in functions and must use recursion. Please help!

Comment: Do not nest `if` statements unless you are confident that there is no other way. In this case, you can get rid of at least two `if` statements.

Comment: `elif isinstance(L[0], list): if True:... else:` - that else clause will never get executed. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot rely upon `reversed` -

```py
def deep_rev(t):
  if isinstance(t, list):
    if not t:
      return []
    else:
      return [ *deep_rev(t[1:]), deep_rev(t[0]) ]
  else:
    return t
    
print(deep_rev([1, [2, [3, 4], [5, [6, 7], 8]]]))
# [[[8, [7, 6], 5], [4, 3], 2], 1]
```

You can trade the `*`-unpacking for list concatenation, `+`, if you wish -

```py
def deep_rev(t):
  if isinstance(t, list):
    if not t:
      return []
    else:
      return deep_rev(t[1:]) + [ deep_rev(t[0]) ]
  else:
    return t
    
print(deep_rev([1, [2, [3, 4], [5, [6, 7], 8]]]))
# [[[8, [7, 6], 5], [4, 3], 2], 1]
```

The two programs above rely on list slicing, `t[1:]`, to recur using a smaller list. Slicing the list for each iteration creates many intermediate values and we can avoid those using a different technique -

```py
def deep_rev(t, k = 0):
  try:
    if isinstance(t, list):
      v = t[k]
      return deep_rev(t, k + 1) + [ deep_rev(v) ]
    else:
      return t
  except IndexError:
    return []
    
print(deep_rev([1, [2, [3, 4], [5, [6, 7], 8]]]))
# [[[8, [7, 6], 5], [4, 3], 2], 1]
```

Comment: If they can't rely upon `reversed`, they could just use reverse the list themselves using `[t[len(t) - i - 1] for i in len(t)]` rather than a functional-esque head/tail method.

Comment: im pretty sure we can not use for or in, and definitely not len(), thats why im having issues

Comment: Jackie, you will be happy to know this answer does not use iterators, list comprehensions, nor does it inspect the `len` of the input

Comment: just a question, what does the asterisk before deep_rev(t[1:] do? We have yet to go over that in class so I'm not sure if i can use it. I know in most cases it does multiplication but it seems to be doing something different here.

Comment: Good question, Jackie. `*` allows you to [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) a list. In this case,`[ *deep_rev(t[1:]), deep_rev(t[0]) ]` is the same as `deep_rev(t[1:]) + [ deep_rev(t[0]) ]`, where `+` is the list concatenation operation. `[1,2] + [3,4] == [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: so i can replace [ *deep_rev(t[1:]), deep_rev(t[0]) ] with deep_rev(t[1:]) + [ deep_rev(t[0]) ]? because when i tried that it did not work (just saw your update will try that) nevermind still confused and not working :( thank you for helping i appreciate it!

Comment: Jackie, you can run the program in [this REPL](https://repl.it/repls/LonelyFussyStatistic)